# Counting number of certain values in each column using pandas and collections

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, collections, counter

I have a txt file including 9 columns and 6 rows. The first 8 columns are either of these values: "1" , "2" and "3". I named these columns from "A" to "H". I named the last column: "class".
The last column is a name : "HIGH". Here is the txt file (data.txt):

```
﻿1,1,1,1,2,1,1,3,HIGH 
1,1,1,2,2,1,1,3,HIGH 
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,HIGH 
1,1,1,2,1,1,1,3,HIGH 
1,1,1,3,2,1,1,3,HIGH 
1,1,1,2,1,2,1,3,HIGH
```

I am trying to count the number of each value in each column and print a list that should have 3 components including the numbers of "1", "2" and "3" values in that column ***respectively***. For example in the first column (e.g A) all values are "1". I expect to get : **A : [6,0,0]**. For the 8th column (e.g. H) where all values are "3", I expect to get: **H : [0,0,6]** or for the fourth column (e.g. D) I have two "1" , three "2" and one "3". So I expect : **D : [2,3,1]**. I tried to get it done using *`pandas`* and *`collection`* . Here is what I did:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df = pd.read_csv('data.txt')
df.columns = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','class']

X = df.ix[:, 0:8].values
y = df.ix[:, 8].values

deg = ['HIGH']

names = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']

for j in range(0, 8):

    freqs = Counter(X[y == deg[0], j])
    print(names[j],':',list(freqs.values()))
```

The output of the above code are empty lists. Here is what it returns:

```
A : []
B : []
C : []
D : []
E : []
F : []
G : []
H : []
```

How can I modify the above code to get what I want?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the following function:

```
def cntInts(col):
    vc = col.value_counts()
    return [ vc.get(i, 0) for i in range(1,4) ]
```

Then apply it and print results:

```
for k, v in df.loc[:, 'A':'H'].apply(cntInts).iteritems():
    print(f'{k}: {v}')
```

For your data sample I got:

```
A: [6, 0, 0]
B: [6, 0, 0]
C: [6, 0, 0]
D: [2, 3, 1]
E: [3, 3, 0]
F: [5, 1, 0]
G: [6, 0, 0]
H: [0, 0, 6]
```

Or maybe it is enough to call just:

```
df.loc[:, 'A':'H'].apply(cntInts)
```

This time the result is a *Series*, which when printed yields:

```
A    [6, 0, 0]
B    [6, 0, 0]
C    [6, 0, 0]
D    [2, 3, 1]
E    [3, 3, 0]
F    [5, 1, 0]
G    [6, 0, 0]
H    [0, 0, 6]
dtype: object
```

## Edit

Following your comments I suppose that there is something wrong with your data.

To trace the actual reason:

1. Define a string variable:

   ```
    txt = '''1,1,1,1,2,1,1,3,HIGH 
    1,1,1,2,2,1,1,3,HIGH 
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,HIGH 
    1,1,1,2,1,1,1,3,HIGH 
    1,1,1,3,2,1,1,3,HIGH 
    1,1,1,2,1,2,1,3,HIGH'''
   ```
2. Run:

   ```
    import io
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), names=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','class'])
   ```
3. Run my code on **my** data. The result should be just as expected.
4. Then read **your** input file (also into *df*) and run my code again.
   Probably there is some difference between your data and mine.
   Especially look for any extra spaces in your input file,
   check also column types (after *read_csv*).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It works fine for all columns except the first column (e.g. A). It returns : A: [1,0,0]. At the beginning of the code I used : df = pd.read_csv('data.txt',header=None)
That might be the issue. Any idea why it is like that?

Comment: If you read with *header=None* then you get column names as consecutive numbers (*0* thru *8*).
To get the intended column names, pass them in *names* parameter and then *header* parameter is not needed. Something like *df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', names=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','class'])*.

Comment: I did as you suggested but I get the same results for column A: import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', names=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','class'])

def cntInts(col):
    vc = col.value_counts()
    return [ vc.get(i, 0) for i in range(1,4) ]

for k, v in df.loc[:, 'A':'H'].apply(cntInts).iteritems():
    print(f'{k}: {v}')

Comment: Why are you surprised that *A: [1,0,0]*? Column *A* contains only values of *1* (6 of them), so this is just the expected result.

Comment: Sorry but it should be the number of "1" values in this column. I mean I should get: A: [6,0,0] NOT [1,0,0] ! The list for each column has 3 components. The first is number of "1" values, the second is number of "2" values and the third is number of "3" values in that column

Comment: After *read_csv* run *df.info()* and check whether columns *A* thru *H* are of *int* type. Apparently there is something wrong with your data.

Comment: I double checked my txt file and I found that there were some extra empty characters in front of each line. After removing them the problem got resolved. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas.Series.value_counts`

```
df.loc[:, :"H"].apply(pd.Series.value_counts).fillna(0).to_dict("l")
```

Output:

```
{'A': [6.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 'B': [6.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 'C': [6.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 'D': [2, 3, 1],
 'E': [3.0, 3.0, 0.0],
 'F': [5.0, 1.0, 0.0],
 'G': [6.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 'H': [0.0, 0.0, 6.0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with collections is select all columns without last, convert `Counter` to `Series`, so output is `DataFrame`, replace missing values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), convert values to integers and last to dictionary by [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
from collections import Counter

d = (df.iloc[:, :-1].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(Counter(x)))
       .fillna(0)
       .astype(int)
       .to_dict("list"))
print (d)
{'A': [6, 0, 0], 'B': [6, 0, 0], 
 'C': [6, 0, 0], 'D': [1, 4, 1], 
 'E': [3, 3, 0], 'F': [5, 1, 0], 
 'G': [6, 0, 0], 'H': [0, 0, 6]}
```

Only pandas solution with `pandas.value_counts`:

```
d = (df.iloc[:, :-1].apply(pd.value_counts)
       .fillna(0)
       .astype(int)
       .to_dict("list"))
print (d)
{'A': [6, 0, 0], 'B': [6, 0, 0],
 'C': [6, 0, 0], 'D': [2, 3, 1], 
 'E': [3, 3, 0], 'F': [5, 1, 0], 
 'G': [6, 0, 0], 'H': [0, 0, 6]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working within python, since your end result is a dictionary:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from itertools import chain, product
import csv    

d = defaultdict(list)
fieldnames = ascii_uppercase[:9]
# test.csv is your file above
with open('test.csv') as csvfile:    
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames = list(fieldnames))
    reader = Counter(chain.from_iterable(row.items() for row in reader))
    for col, value in product(fieldnames, ("1","2","3")):
        if col != fieldnames[-1]:
            d[col].append(reader.get((col,value), 0))
```

print(d)

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'A': [6, 0, 0],
             'B': [6, 0, 0],
             'C': [6, 0, 0],
             'D': [2, 3, 1],
             'E': [3, 3, 0],
             'F': [5, 1, 0],
             'G': [6, 0, 0],
             'H': [0, 0, 6]})
```